# Desktop Windows Issue

Tags: release-freya, desktop

Hello I have a problem.

After I install Elementary OS Freya, I see something unusual like this picture.

[image]

I cant close that window, It's really annoying

Comment: i deleted it already

Comment: -_- okay, so you know about this problem?

Comment: present upvoted and marked star...I will try...no exact answer.

Comment: whatever, yes, please

Comment: open terminal and run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall elementary-desktop` ..

Comment: @Vannrith does the command solved the problem or dup Q?

Comment: first I reinstall DE, then I remove Nemo... and reboot.. now everything is working fine, thanks you guys ;)